# Searching a web part that displays a file share

Tags: web-part, search

I have a web part in SharePoint that displays a file share. I want to know if there is a way I can search for documents within that web part?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to create a Search content source withn central administration that points to this file share and set up a crawl schedule to index the content. You'd also want to create a search scope that isolates that content source data. Then you can use the Sharepoint search scopes drop down to select the proper scope and search through the file share.